# ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to plot boxplot using ggplot2. sample data is like this.

`> sampe`

```
count genotype
71       mt
50       mt
71       mt
95       wt
60       mt
63       mt
75       mt
82       wt
93       wt
87       wt
61       mt
102       wt
60       mt
78       wt
78       wt
87       wt
84       wt
104       wt
81       wt
85       mt


> qplot(factor(genotype),count,data=sampe,geom="boxplot")
```

The above command produces plot like this:
[image]

what's wrong here?? why is it plotting like this?? Even this below code produces same output.

```
ggplot(sampe,aes(x=factor(genotype),y=count))+geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Your code works for me. What version are you `using:packageDescription("ggplot2")$Version` - the latest version is 0.9.3.1

Comment: It works well here. What gives `class(sampe$count)` ? I guess it's a `factor` ?

Comment: It seems that your count values are stored as factor in your data, that's only way I can reproduce your plot.

Comment: Hi,
@csgillespie - I am using the recent package (0.9.3.1)
@juba @Didzis -  thank for pointing out about factor. I changed my code `qplot(factor(genotype),as.numeric(count),data=sampe,geom="boxplot") `
its working fine now. 
Thank you all.

Comment: @poisonAlien you can answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: @poisonAlien, when a numeric value is stored as a factor you **should not** directly convert to numeric. you should do: **as.numeric(as.character(count))**. please take care of this!

Comment: @Arun - Thank you for the tip. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok.. I 'll answer my own question. As per the suggestion count values were stored as factor. Converting them to numeric did the trick

```
qplot(factor(genotype),as.numeric(count),data=sampe,geom="boxplot")
```

Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your Y-axis is not actually count, R understand count as a variable.
Actually you only need to group the data by genotype and than do ggplot2.

```
df %>% group_by(genotype)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(x=genotype, y = count))
```